# Python requests GET fails but CURL command working

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to make a get request to a webpage but I keep getting a 404 error using Python2.7 with `requests` package.  However, using CURL I get a successful response and it works with the browser.

Python

```
r = requests.get('https://www.ynet.co.il/articles/07340L-446694800.html')
r.status_code
  404
r.headers
  {'backend-cache-control': '', 'Content-Length': '20661', 'WAI': '02',
  'X-me': '08', 'vg_id': '1', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
  'Last-Modified': 'Sun, 20 May 2018 01:20:04 GMT', 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'V-TTL': '47413', 'Date': 'Sun, 20 May 2018 14:55:21 GMT', 'VX-Cache': 'HIT',
  'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes'}
r.reason
  'Not Found'
```

CURL

```
curl https://www.ynet.co.il/articles/07340L-446694800.html
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, the url returns 404 with a browser (and propably `curl`) too. You can get the content with `r.text`

Comment: that is a good point and observation @t.m.adam I wonder why that is.  Do you suppose the server is explicitly returning a status code of 404 along with valid content?  something like `return render_template(...), 404` as an example in flask

Comment: It seeems that the site returns the home page in case of 404 error. I think the page you should request is `/articles/0,7340,L-4466948,00.html` (with commas).

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct, it works for some other sites (see https://repl.it/repls/MemorableUpbeatExams ).

This site loads for me in the browser, so I confirm your issue.

It might be that they block Python requests, because they don't want their site scraped and analysed by bots, but they forgot to block curl.

What you are doing is probably violating www.ynet.co.il terms of use, and you shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

A 404 is displayed when:

1. The URL is incorrect and  the response is actually accurate.
2. Trailing spaces in the URL
3. The website may not like HTTP(S) requests coming from Python code. Change your headers by adding "www." to your Referer url.

`resp = requests.get(r'http://www.xx.xx.xx.xx/server/rest/line/125')`

or

```
headers = {
       'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
    }
result = requests.get('https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk', headers=headers)
```